# How to add ViewPager with fragments to EditText autocomplete suggestions view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, autocomplete, android-viewpager

I'm tasked with building a UI similar to this for composing emails.

[image]

When the user starts typing in the `To:` field, the app needs to bring up the autosuggest dialog with matching records in two tabs. Most examples online show how to do autocomplete with a simple RecyclerView and ArrayAdapter. I haven't been able to find any help on embedding a ViewPager in the suggestions dialog. 
Do you have any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: The way it can work if you implement a viewpager having 2 tabs and 2 fragments ( same fragment but different instance) each containing the recyclerview and implementing the filterable over adapter and then adding watcher over edittext and calling the filterable whenever something is typed.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll give it a try. Thanks Gautam!